# Execute code on org-after-todo-state-change-hook on entries with specified tag

Tags: emacs, elisp, org-mode

I've got some org files with content as below:

```
* HOLD Some todo heading             :project:
  #+BEGIN_SRC shell
  grunt watch
  #+END_SRC
* TODO Some other heading             :test:
  #+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
  (message "TEST")
  #+END_SRC
```

I want to switch from `HOLD` to `INPROGRESS` state on clock-in. This is easy and I got it.

Then on `org-after-todo-state-change-hook` I want to execute code included in entry but only on specific TAGS.

So, I got:

```
(defun tester/after-change-hook()
  "Test function on hook."
  (when (string= org-state "INPROGRESS") 

    ;; DO SOMETHING on entry with 'project' tag

    ;; DO SOMETHING on entry with 'test' tag

    ;; MAYBE TRY TO EXECUTE CODE ON entry with 'project' tag

    ;; MAYBE TRY TO EXECUTE CODE ON entry with 'test' tag

  )
)
(add-hook 'org-after-todo-state-change-hook 'tester/after-change-hook)
```

Unfortunately, I don't know how to write a function to execute code on specific tag or execute inline code on specific tag.

I've been trying with `org-scan-tags` function or `org-element-map`.

I can see that [other people can make use of them](http://sachachua.com/blog/2013/01/emacs-org-display-projects-with-a-few-subtasks-in-the-agenda-view/).

But unfortunately all this Lisp stuff is like a black magic for me.
I don't know how to write function that will test tags on currently clocked task.
Could someone help me with this lisp syntax?
In theory I know which functions are required to do what I want.
In real life I don't know how to write this in lisp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to match a member in a list of tags would be to use something like `(member "test" tags)` -- see example below where the presence of tag named `test` will yield a congratulations message, or a go-fish message if the tag named `test` is not present.  You can also use a regexp to match whole words or parts of words, but that is beyond the scope of this example.

---

Here is a 4-step approach to test the example below.   [The example was tested by @lawlist using Org version 8.2.5c.]

- **(1)**  Copy and paste my entire code into your `.emacs` file; save the file; and, restart Emacs.
- **(2)**  Open a new buffer and type:

  ```
  * This is a task. :test:lawlist:
  ```
- **(3)**  `M-x org-mode`
- **(4)**  Place the cursor anywhere on the line you just typed and:   `M-x example`

Once you get the example up and running (*without making any modifications*), then you can slowly make your own modifications -- keep testing your new code at various stages along the way, so that any wrong turns in your coding will not get too far out of hand (which would make debugging that much more difficult).

---

```
(require 'org)

(require 'org-element)

(defun example ()
(interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (org-back-to-heading t)
    (let* (
        (element (org-element-at-point))
        (title (org-element-property :title element))
        (tags (org-element-property :tags element)))
      (cond
        ((and
            (equal title "")
            (not (equal tags nil)))
          (error "The `title` cannot be blank."))
        ((and
            (equal tags nil)
            (not (equal title "")))
          (error "The `tags` cannot be blank."))
        ((and
            (equal title "")
            (equal tags nil))
          (error "The `title` and `tags` cannot be blank."))
        ((and
            (not (equal tags nil))
            (not (equal title "")))
          (message "TITLE:  %s  |  TAG(S):  %s" title tags)
          (if (member "test" tags)
            (message "Congratulations:  You found a match.")
            (message "Uh-oh -- no match -- go fish!")))  ))))
```

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot make it working with your example. I cannot message any tags. Problem is that I just don't know how to get current task... 'object' ? I cannot get 'element' because I got message: "save-excursion: Symbol's function definition is void: element"

Comment: If you have an older version of `org-mode`, you may need to add this to your `.emacs` file:  `(require 'org-element)`.  I'll add that to my example.  I added steps 1 to 4 in the answer to get you started -- I removed my previous abbreviated comment that essentially said the same thing.  My usage of the `let`-bound term `element` is contingent upon it being defined above as being equal to `org-element-at-point`.

Comment: You are right. Thank you very much. I just had bug in my test code. I had to understand 'let' function better and now I got it functional. As I can see I can hardcode some tag and test if it's member of tags list, than instead of message I can put some other code or lambda. Yet another question is: how to parse entry content and run shell code if is defined in source code block?

Comment: I recommend putting together a sample attempted function and opening a new question for the shell code and source code block issue.  I may take a stab at answering that question also once I better understand exactly what it looks like that is being searched for . . . :)  I see I indented the condition a little too much, perhaps that was part of your confusion -- I'll bring it back one indentation level -- it may help others who read this thread in the future.